# Writing to Azure Cosmos , Throughput RU

Tags: azure, apache-spark, throughput, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

We are planning in writing 10000 JSON Documents to Azure Cosmos DB (MongoDB), Does the Throughput Units matter, if so, can we increase for the batch load and set it back to low number

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that. The lowest the RUs can be is 400. Scale up before you're about to do your insert and then turn it down again. As always, that part can be automated if you know when the documents are going to be inserted.

Check out the [DocumentClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient?view=azure-dotnet) documentation and more specifically [ReplaceOfferAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.replaceofferasync?view=azure-dotnet).

Comment: Can you tell how many RU needed for 10000 JSON Documents to Azure Cosmos DB (MongoDB)

Comment: That's not a simple question, @DeepakSharma! There are many things to factor in such as: what size is each document, how many columns within the document are indexed, how fast do you want to write them in. Check out this blog post for more info and how to measure it: https://azure-development.com/2018/12/11/calculating-request-units-in-azure-cosmos-db/

Answer (score 0):

You can scale the RU/sec allocation up or down at any time. You'll want to look at your insertion cost (RU cost is returned in a header) for a typical document, to get an idea of how many documents you might be able to write, per second, before getting throttled.

Also keep in mind: if you scale your RU out beyond what an underlying physical partition can provide, Cosmos DB will scale out your collection to have additional physical partitions. This means you might not be able to scale your RU back down to the bare minimum later (though you *will* be able to scale down).

Comment: Can you tell how many RU needed for 10000 JSON Documents to Azure Cosmos DB (MongoDB)

Comment: @DeepakSharma - there's no direct answer: RU needs are determined by your queries & reads, along with physical storage required. I'd suggest starting with the Cosmos DB docs around this for more information.